# What is the intuition behind $\lim_{x \to{+}\infty}{f(x)^{g(x)}}=e^{(\lim_{x \to{+}\infty}{(f(x)-1)\cdot g(X)})}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the intuition behind $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to{+}\infty}{f(x)^{g(x)}}=e^{\Big(\displaystyle\lim_{x \to{+}\infty}{(f(x)-1)\cdot g(X)}\Big)}$? This is actually a formula I need to remember so I was wondering if there were some quick intuitive or geometric reasoning behind it that I could use without going for a lengthy derivation?
I actually would welcome some guidance regarding any $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to{a}}{f(x)^{g(x)}}=e^{\Big(\displaystyle\lim_{x \to{a}}{(f(x)-1)\cdot g(X)}\Big)}$ where it is given that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to{a}}f(x) = 1$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to{a}}g(x) = \infty$

Comment: This is not true in general. You are probably assuming that $f(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$; even then some additional conditions on $g$ are needed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I forgot to mention that, I was in a bit of a hurry when posting the question, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write your RHS as
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-1)g(x)\right).$$
You seem to have some implicit assumptions. First of all, if $f(x)>0$ then
$$f(x)^{g(x)}=\exp\left(g(x)\ln(f(x))\right).$$
If also $f(x)\to1$ as $x\to\infty$ then $\ln(f(x))\sim(f(x)-1)$ as $x\to\infty$.
This is basically
$$\lim_{t\to1}\frac{\ln t}{t-1}=1.$$
In this case, then $(f(x)-1)g(x)$ tends to a nonzero limit $L$ iff $g(x)\ln(f(x))$ tends to $L$.

Comment: I actually forgot to mention the conditions, I've edited the question.

Comment: @Hema: you will be better off remembering the formula $(\log t) /(t-1)\to 1$ as $t\to 1$ rather than the formula in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The very definition of arbitrary exponentiation of reals is that  $$f(x)^{g(x)}=\exp(g(x)\ln f(x)).$$ 
As the exponential is continuous, we should find $$\tag1\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)\ln f(x)$$ and exponentiate that. The *intuition* behind your proposed formula is then that $\ln x\approx x-1$ for $x\approx 1$ (because $\ln1=0$ and $\ln'1=1$). But as said in comments and other answers, the *applicability* may only be given under additional constrains oin the behaviours of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I actually forgot to mention the conditions, I've edited the question.